# HTML <DIV> hide / show using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two embed code/sections on a single page.  What I am wanting is to make the Social Media logo clickable and then the embed for the corresponding embedded social media will be visible and the other is hidden.  I was able to do this with one  section but the code was all html.  The problem is that Twitter embed has a  section in the middle of the embed and it is messing up the output when I do it the old way.

This is the old code that I have mostly working (minus the embed not show correctly)

```
    <body onload="updateForm(media)">
        <label>
            <input type="image" src="\CST-WebPage\media files\social media\youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:100px" name="media" value="ty" onclick="updateForm(this)">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="image" src="\CST-WebPage\media files\social media\twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:100px" name="media" value="tw" onclick="updateForm(this)">
        </label>
        <div id="SM"></div>
    </body>
```

```
function updateForm(control) {
  if (control.value == "tw") {
  document.getElementById("SM").innerHTML = twitter;
    }
    else {
  document.getElementById("SM").innerHTML = youtube;
    }
}

var youtube = '<div>\
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLDNv6o8iIDrw6ETcAy8s3xHgn2UdjpZ-e" width="600" height="400"allowfullscreen scrollable="yes"></iframe>\
      <p id="success"></p>\
</div>';

var twitter = '<div>\
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="600" data-height="400" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/clanshocktac?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by clanshocktac</a>\
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>\
    </div>';
```

Instead of having `<div id='SM'></div>` I figure it would be easier to make it `<div id='youtube'>` and `<div id='twitter'>`

Thank in advance for any help or insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set or remove the `hidden` attribute to elements with id `twitter` or `youtube`.

```
function updateForm(control) {
  if (control.value == "tw") {
     document.getElementById("twitter").removeAttribute('hidden');
     document.getElementById("youtube").setAttribute('hidden', true);
  } else {
     document.getElementById("youtube").removeAttribute('hidden');
     document.getElementById("twitter").setAttribute('hidden', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, my mind was drawing a complete blank.  Now I need to figure out if there is a way to pause the video when it is hidden

Comment: Yes, you can use the youtube player api: https://www.youtube.com/player_api, and try with YT.Player.pauseVideo() function